# java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: RandomAccessFile.finalize() timed out after 10 seconds

Tags: java, android, timeout, randomaccessfile

Our company's app encounter an exception, but I can not find the specific reasons, we can help me?

```
`id.finalize()
id is a confused class name
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: id.finalize() timed out after 10 seconds
at libcore.io.Posix.fstat(Native Method)
at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.fstat(ForwardingOs.java:56)
at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.close(BlockGuardOs.java:60)
at libcore.io.IoUtils.close(IoUtils.java:43)
at java.io.RandomAccessFile.close(RandomAccessFile.java:166)
at java.io.RandomAccessFile.finalize(RandomAccessFile.java:175)
at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize(Daemons.java:194)
at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run(Daemons.java:176)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Comment: Best thing to do is find out where a `RandomAccessFile` is used (opened) and never closed. Code should never rely on `finalize()` to do resource cleanup. Fix the underlying problem, and this error should never happen.

Comment: I have found the code call, but I did not Override   the finalize  method。

Comment: Didn't think you did. `RandomAccessFile` did. The fact that the `finalize()` has anything to do is caused by a flaw in your logic, i.e. lack of adequately closing the `RandomAccessFile` when done with it.

Comment: Is not it necessary to manually call with close

Comment: You **must** close it manually. Do not rely of finalize to do it for you.

Comment: OK thank   you very mush!

Comment: I'm really sorry，This question is not necessarily present, and now I can not reproduce the problem, there is no good advice